# What is this Javascript error message about?: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a React-Redux app that is currently working effectively, in the sense that it is able to call up an API to fetch, post, update and destroy as requested. Although the calls are carried out successfully, the page where the data is rendered is preceded by the following window, bearing an error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
(anonymous function)
src/components/Journeymen.js:40
  
  39 |     {journeymen.map((journeyman) => (
> 40 |       <SwiperSlide key={journeyman.id} >
  41 |         <Link to={`/journeymen/${journeyman.id}`} className="text-decoration-none">
```

As soon as I close the error message window, however, I can see all the requested data rendered as expected, including the Journeyman.id itself, which the error message window had just told me was "undefined". Can’t understand what is the issue.

This is the part of the Journeyman component that is pertinent:

```
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2 className="mt-3 mx-5">Journeymen</h2>
      <Swiper … lots of Swiper attributes listed here…>
        <div className="">
          {journeymen.map((journeyman) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={journeyman.id} >
              <Link to={`/journeymen/${journeyman.id}`} className="text-decoration-none">
                <div className="card my-3 mx-3">
                  <div className="">
                    <div className="my-3 mx-5">
                      <img className="" src={journeyman.image_url} width="150" height="150" alt="journeyman-img" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="my-3 mx-5">
                      <p className="text-secondary">
                        <strong>Id: </strong>
                        {journeyman.id}
                      </p>
                     …lots of other journeyman attributes rendered here
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Link>
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  )
```

Can someone help me understand what is going on and how to resolve the matter? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `journeyman.id`.    <-  journeyman is undefined.   Try console logging your journeymen arrray, one of the items is undefined.

Comment: Thank you @Keith. I edited the heading on my question in accordance. Still don't understand in what way `id` is "undefined" and how to fix that.

Comment: Skip undefined values by doing `journeymen.filter(Boolean).map((journeyman) => .......` But you should probably look into the source of these undefined values and avoid that they get into your array in the first place.

Comment: It seems you've a `journeymen` array with at least 1 undefined array element, e.g. at least one `journeyman` that is undefined, and can't access an `id` property. Please [edit] the post to include a complete [mcve] and an example of the data being fetched and set into the `journeymen` state.

Answer (score -1):

Echoing @Keith's comment, this means your `journeymen` array contains undefined values. Try debugging it at an earlier point to find where exactly.

Comment: Precisely, what puzzles me is that when I console log the response I get form the API call, I am getting the id. This is the form it takes `data
: 
{id: 11, name: 'German', skill: 'Dog Catcher', country: 'Argentina', city: 'Cordoba', …}`

Comment: But that's for a single journeyman. The problem seems to be with the *list*. I think including in your question how you fetch this list might be helpful.